# I tried find how people show spaces in vs code but I didn't found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know it's trivial question but I watched many tutorials and I found people in vs code when they press space it show like a point in the editor and I thought its extension but I watched and read 25+ articles and videos about useful vs code extension but I didn't found any thing its seems you can activate it in the settings but I tried without any result and really feel hopeless...

Answer (score 1):

This is the ID of the setting: `editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters`
You can just search up, `invis` then it should be the first one that pops up.
[image: Invisible Characters]